# For questions edited to contain answers, should I rollback and repost?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, rollbacks

I notice that helpful new posters, after finding their own solution, will edit their question to include the answer they find. Since questions are best marked as solved, and since we want questions/answers to be separated for the API, I tend to roll these back and repost them myself, marked as "on behalf of the OP".

It would of course be better for OPs to do this themselves, so that their work is correctly attributed and so they can garner answer votes if they wish. However, if I ask for this rollback/edit, that request is often ignored. What is the best approach to tidying here?

Comment: Yes, rollback and post their answer as community wiki.

Comment: Ah, of course! I'd forgotten about that feature - good idea @Knight.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I never thought to do that. This is a great approach, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

In that situation you should rollback this edit, and paste the answer as a "community wiki" post.